# Printing a 2D print function in C

Tags: c

I feel that I am extremely close to getting this correct, but I am missing out on a vital point of calling the print function in my main method. I am a bit out of practice so simply a push in the right direction would help. My code is supposed to print out the 2D array in row major fashion, followed by column major fashion.

```
// ArrayPointer.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// a: array pointer, m: # of rows, n: # of columns  
void printMatrixRowMajor(int *a, int m, int n){

    printf("Matrix row major fashion:\n");

        int x[3][4];
        a = &(x[0][0]);

        for (m=0;m<3;m++){
            for (n=0;n<4;n++){
                printf("%d ", *(a + (m*4)+n));  
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
}
// a: array pointer, m: # of rows, n: # of columns
void printMatrixColMajor(int *a, int m, int n){ 
    printf("\nMatrix column major fashion:\n");

        int x[3][4];
        a = &(x[0][0]);

        for (n=0;n<4;n++){
            for (m=0;m<3;m++){
                printf("%d ", *(a + x[m][n]));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
}
main()
{
    int row, col;
    int x[3][4], *xptr;

    xptr = &(x[0][0]);
    printf("%d", printMatrixRowMajor);


}
```

Comment: Please also ask a question so we can answer. What’s wrong with the code? What do you need help with specifically? And why don’t you just use `x[m][n]` instead of trying to play with pointers?

Comment: Your local arrays `int x[3][4];` do not contain any data, and you overwrite the function argument with its address. So the functions are getting `m` and `n` but no data to use. In `main()` the `printf("%d", printMatrixRowMajor);` is calling a function without passing any arguments, and again, there is no data in the array. You are also trying to `printf`its return value, but it is a `void` function. May I suggest you first using a function to print a single value passed, then move on to a 1D array, before attempting the 2D array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your slightly modified code could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// a: array pointer, m: # of rows, n: # of columns
void printMatrixRowMajor(int *a, int m, int n) {

    printf("Matrix row major fashion:\n");

    for (int y = 0; y < m; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            printf("%d ", *(a + (y * n) + x));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int x[3][4] = {{1, 2,  3,  4},
                   {5, 6,  7,  8},
                   {9, 10, 11, 12}};
    printMatrixRowMajor(x, 3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

**Changes**

- in main there is some matrix data defined
- printMatrixRowMajor is called (not printf of a function pointer)
- two index variables are used to traverse the matrix elements in printMatrixRowMajor
- the dimensions of the matrix is used to visit the matrix elements
- the main function signature adopted
- return 0 added to main

**Output in Console**

If you run the program it gives the following output on the console:

```
Matrix row major fashion:
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12
```

Comment: I do see how that print will work in main, but I need to somehow call the function like you would be able to in a higher language using that exact one. Pointer, row, column.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to call the function with a pointer - so you can do sth like `int *ptr = (int *) x; printMatrixRowMajor(ptr, 3, 4);`

Comment: Absolutely, that was what I was trying to do.